# How to schedule restart of Windows machine at the end of recipe run instead of chef-client run?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am currently using [WindowsRebootHandler](http://docs.opscode.com/lwrp_windows.html), to restart the machine at the end of chef-client run (i.e, after running all the recipes).

Is there any way to schedule restart of the machine at the end of each recipe run instead of chef-client run?

Even when I tried with timeout 0 on `windows_reboot` function, restart happened at the end of chef-client run.

Comment: @Draco I want to install some of the Windows packages before installing my application. For example, I want to install say .NET framework, restart the machine and then install my application.

Comment: No, and it would probably be a bad idea. You want to schedule a reboot

Comment: @sethvargo Yes, I am scheduling reboot using `windows_reboot` function. But, reboot happened after executing all the recipes in the run_list. My requirement is to stop the chef-client run when one recipe action is completed and restart the machine. And after restart continue with the rest of the recipes.

Comment: Right. And I'm explaining that's a bad idea and it's not a good idea. You should consider approaching the problem differently.

Comment: @sethvargo Is there any alternate way chef provides to handle these type of requirements.

Comment: Not really - that's why I think you should approach the problem differently

Answer (score 0):

Good idea or not, here's a way of doing it:

Have the chef client start in an environment called 'firstrun'.
Add a recipe to the 'firstrun' environment for your role which does the following:

1. Do your installs.
2. Change the chef client config to run in the production environment.
3. Reboot windows

Windows will then start up and run chef in the 'production' environment, in which you can run all your other recipes.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add this as an answer since I stumbled upon this question myself.

You can include recipes depending on if a reboot is pending like so:

```
include_recipe 'mycookbook::second_recipe' unless reboot_pending?

windows_reboot 30
    timeout 30
    reason 'scheduled reboot'
    action :nothing
end

some_task 'stuff' do
    ...
    notifies :request, 'windows_reboot[30]', :delayed
end
```

The idea would be to have a dependency chain of recipes so that the end of the chef run would be the first recipe to request a restart.

Alex Vinyar has a [Github](https://github.com/vinyar/chef_win_reboots) repository for this and other patterns to handle rebooting in Chef.